Thyristor Choppers
I want to simulate this circuit to analyse its behavior: 
First I tried working the theoretic part of it: we suppose that the capacitor is charged initially thus \$ V_c = V_1 , i_l = -i_c = 0 \$ and we also suppose that the thyristor doesn’t have a gate impulsion initially thus \$V_{D_1} = E, i_{D_1} = 0\$ thus \$ i_{R_1} = 0 \$
at t = T, we send an impulsion at the gate, thus \$V_{R_1} = E , i_{R_1} = \frac{E}{R_1}\$ and \$V_c - V_l = V_{D_1} = 0 \iff V_c - LC \frac{\partial^2 V_c}{dt^2} = 0 \iff V_c = V_1 \cos(\frac{t}{\sqrt{LC}})\$ and since \$ i_l = -i_c = -C \frac{\partial V_c}{\partial t} = V_1 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{C}{L}} \sin(\frac{t}{\sqrt{LC}})\$ and \$ i_{D_1} = i_{R_1} + i_l = \frac{V_1}{R_1} +V_1 \cdot \sqrt{\frac{C}{L}} \sin(\frac{t}{\sqrt{LC}})\$
What I theorically plotted doesn't match what the professor did below. What is this U0 he is talking about where did it come from? I would like if someone overexplain this to me, along with this other protection circuit that my professor used which he said it enhances the circuit:


Questions: Q1.  What do you mean by "this other protection circuit", are you referring to the diode that is anti-parallel with the SCR? Q2. "what is this U0 he is talking about"  Where does this appear on the whiteboard drawing?

Q1 yes you are right im referring to the diode in anti-parallel with SCR and the capacitor in series with the inductance that has a diode in parallel to it (its the circuit highlighted in green). Q2: it appears in the first graph  where there is (E+U0)/R @FabioBarone

What’s “gate impulsion”? Do you mean gate pulse?

The Uo is the voltage that appears on the SCR when it conducts.
Here is what I simulated with microcap v12.
Note that the load must be a minimum (> 40-50 Ohm) for such a behavior.
When Load is < ~ 40 Ohm, the behavior is more different ...
When the switch is open ...

And when the switch is closed ...

What we see is that C1 is recharged "fast" when the diode is used.
And the current through the resistor load is most "rapidly" nullified.
The SCR can be very fast retriggered for another ON phase.

but why is there extra components in the circuit? like the diode and the extra resistance in the LC circuit

@KnowledgeSeeker  By " extra components", do you mean the Ls drawn in red in series with the SCR and the diode?  If "yes", then these would be either intentional small-value inductors that limit rate of change of current, or they may represent unintentional or "parasitic" components such as the inductance of a piece of wire.  Similar for the R, in the LC circuit, real-world (not ideal) components such as Ls and Cs have "parasitic" resistance.  In fact, real-world Cs have parasitic series R and series L, and real-world Ls have parasitic Rs and parallel C.
